# jQuery Touchwipe - disable default scrolling for 1 axis only

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Im using the jQuery Touchwipe plugin:
http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library

With preventDefaultEvents: true its possible to dissable the default dragging behavour on an iPhone. However what I need is to dissable the default behavious in 1 axis only. I need users to be able to drag to scroll up and down, but dragging from left to right needs to be disabled and my function will fire instead. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same need and extended the touchwipe plugin to pass the event to the wipeLeft, wipeRight, wipeUp and wipeDown callbacks. That allows me to set `preventDefaultEvents: false` in config and then in my specific callbacks if needed, do first thing: `e.preventDefault();`.

I sent modifications to plugin author.

The modified plugin:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.touchwipe = function(settings) {
    var config = {
            min_move_x: 20,
            min_move_y: 20,
            wipeLeft: function(e) { },
            wipeRight: function(e) { },
            wipeUp: function(e) { },
            wipeDown: function(e) { },
            preventDefaultEvents: true
    };

    if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

    this.each(function() {
        var startX;
        var startY;
        var isMoving = false;

        function cancelTouch() {
            this.removeEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
            startX = null;
            isMoving = false;
        }

        function onTouchMove(e) {
            if(config.preventDefaultEvents) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            if(isMoving) {
                var x = e.touches[0].pageX;
                var y = e.touches[0].pageY;
                var dx = startX - x;
                var dy = startY - y;
                if(Math.abs(dx) >= config.min_move_x) {
                    cancelTouch();
                    if(dx > 0) {
                        config.wipeLeft(e);
                    }
                    else {
                        config.wipeRight(e);
                    }
                }
                else if(Math.abs(dy) >= config.min_move_y) {
                        cancelTouch();
                        if(dy > 0) {
                            config.wipeDown(e);
                        }
                        else {
                            config.wipeUp(e);
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        function onTouchStart(e)
        {
            if (e.touches.length == 1) {
                startX = e.touches[0].pageX;
                startY = e.touches[0].pageY;
                isMoving = true;
                this.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);
            }
        }
        if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
            this.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);
        }
    });

    return this;
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I have tried this but when dragging left/right, the screen still drags, the e.preventDefault() isn't fully working or it is called too late or something. I tested on simulator... is it different on an actual phone?

Comment: Huangism: the wipe functions need to take event as attr, such as `wipeLeft: function(e) {...}` then call `e.preventDafult();` as first thing.

Comment: The official plugin works fine with left/right swipe. But that breaks page scroll. And this one lets page scroll work fine but now left/right swipe isn't working.  `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $(".unit").touchwipe({ wipeLeft: function(e) { e.preventDafult(); alert('to left'); }, wipeRight: function(e) { e.preventDafult(); alert('to right'); } }); });`