# Touch slide to work only on x-axis

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

I am having an issue with a script. It is related to [jQuery Touchwipe - disable default scrolling for 1 axis only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774253/jquery-touchwipe-disable-default-scrolling-for-1-axis-only). I am doing a slide out menu (like facebook adroid) for a webpage. The script in the url is the one I am using. All I need if or the x-axis to have preventDefaultEvents: true on it. At the moment, I can't sroll in any direction. I would to scroll up and down only and have left and right with functions.

I have the script in the url and

```
$("#my-div").touchwipe({
  wipeLeft: function() { $.closeslide.close();},
  wipeRight: function() {},
  wipeUp: function() {},
  wipeDown: function() {},
  min_move_x: 20,
  min_move_y: 0,
});
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: i think `min_move_y: 0,` might be a problem

Comment: Ok, i changed it to  min_move_y: 20. But still not vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think there have already been asked this question. Here is the answer [jQuery Touchwipe - disable default scrolling for 1 axis only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774253/jquery-touchwipe-disable-default-scrolling-for-1-axis-only)

Best wishes!
Deni